# Selecting values using day as a variable

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, days

In my project one of the tasks is to run a daily report of all new reports and jobs that have been conducted in the preceding 24 hours easy..
However they throw in a funny in terms of the repair crews do not work over the weekend however reports could naturally still come in. So Monday morning a report will be produced show all reports from the past 3 days eg fri - mon and any repairs conducted on the fri similar to the code below.

One solution which I find unpracticle is to show two date fieds and the user selects fri & mon date like code I produced below for another function.

```
SELECT `defect_Id`, `job_Id`, `date_On_Task`, `description`, `resolved` 
FROM `job`
WHERE `date_On_Task` >= '$date1'
AND `date_On_Task` <= '$date2'
AND `repair_Team` = '$repair_Team'
AND `resolved` = 3"
```

I would like to be able to use if statement with nested sql statements if day = Monday show * <3days if not show * <1 day.

The select statement is an issue I'm struggling to find any information on a variable of a day for example on click `CURDATE()` would select current date but can SQL convert a date to a day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get rid of both date pickers from your application.

For that you could apply your logic in `WHERE` clause using `CASE` statement:

```
WHERE 
  CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) = 0 
       THEN `date_On_Task` = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 DAY
       ELSE `date_On_Task` = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  END
```

[`WEEKDAY()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) function returns `0` for Monday and will cause the following where clause to apply on Mondays:

```
WHERE `date_On_Task` = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

If the function returns anything else (from 1 to 6 meaning Tuesday to Sunday) get jobs that have been performed yesterday.

Substracting days from a particular date is straightforward. You could use `DATE_SUB()` or substract `INTERVAL` like that:

```
<DATE HERE> - INTERVAL <NUMBER HERE> DAY
```

---

Your full query would look:

```
SELECT `defect_Id`, `job_Id`, `date_On_Task`, `description`, `resolved` 
FROM `job`
WHERE 
  CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) = 0 
       THEN `date_On_Task` = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 DAY
       ELSE `date_On_Task` = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  END
  AND `repair_Team` = '$repair_Team'
  AND `resolved` = 3
```

Comment: My code does exactly that. Please read the answer again. `WEEKDAY()` function returns `0` for Monday.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of like this(?):

```
WHERE
    [date_On_Task] BETWEEN
    CASE
        WHEN DATENAME(DW, GETDATE()) = 'Monday' THEN CAST(GETDATE() - 3 AS date)
        WHEN DATENAME(DW, GETDATE()) = 'Sunday' THEN CAST(GETDATE() - 2 AS date)
        ELSE CAST(GETDATE() - 1 AS date)
    END
        AND
    CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
```

Comment: This is more what I would expect to see, you can assume the manager would not be accessing the intranet site on the weekend also so there is no need for the Sunday statement.

Comment: Yes, it's up to you how you'd want to use the logic, but this is the general idea. You could just remove the 'Sunday' line if you were confident it would never be used.